# PHP Search Multidimensional Array from JSON for a specific value

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the 'name' value from the object with the highest 'bytes' value. My code so far is:

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('https://yivesmirror.com/api/spigot');

$json = json_decode($str, true);

echo get_highest($json);

function get_highest($json)
{
   foreach($json as $key => $val)
   {
      if ( is_array($val) ) $json[$key] = get_highest( $val );
   }
   sort($json);

   return array_pop($json);
}

?>
```

From this JSON file:

```
{
    "spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar": {
        "name": "spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar",
        "size": {
            "human": "40.52MB",
            "bytes": 42488067
        },
        "date": {
            "human": "July 25, 2017",
            "epoch": 1501040531
        }
    }
},
{
    "spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1364.jar": {
        "name": "spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1364.jar",
        "size": {
            "human": "4.10MB",
            "bytes": 4297941
        },
        "date": {
            "human": "July 25, 2017",
            "epoch": 1501040531
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is searching all keys and giving me the 'epoch' value not the 'bytes' value.
How can I:

- Only find the highest value from the 'bytes' object?
- Get the 'name' value from where it found the largest 'bytes' value (as above)?

Comment: Remove "true" from the json_decode() so you can get objects.  Then you can use OOP notation!

Comment: Since your question has been put on hold, it's not obvious how I might give you the answer, but in testing, I found that there is sometimes an element named "spigot-latest.jar" which appears to contain exactly what you want.  Otherwise this URL will show what I did to get the info. It shows the source at the end of the output. https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_snl.php

Comment: Thank you Ray! That is exactly what I was after and thank you for the comments on each function!

Answer (score 0):

When I run your PHP it gives me: 
`Notice: Undefined index: urls in C:\xampp\htdocs\FOLDER\FILE`

But when I changed

`$json = json_decode($str, true);`

to

`$json = var_dump(json_decode($str, true));`

And remade the `$version` var using `$version = $json['urls']['free']`

Then I wrote: `echo $version`
and it gave me:

```
array(294) { [0]=> array(1) { ["spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(35) "spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar" ["version"]=> array(1) { ["minecraft"]=> string(4) "1.12" } ["size"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(7) "40.52MB" ["bytes"]=> int(42488067) } ["date"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(13) "July 25, 2017" ["epoch"]=> int(1501040531) } ["hashes"]=> array(2) { ["md5"]=> string(32) "482dc5b3273e3c9aa4ed38da73e9e9f2" ["sha1"]=> string(40) "921ad2d9fbe9bfbbd6d48a4c15196d20f265ca5c" } ["urls"]=> array(2) { ["paid"]=> string(119) "http://sh.st/st/40260a458161ce19c15c6bc46ebe3bd6/http://yivesmirror.com/grab/spigot/spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar" ["free"]=> string(71) "http://yivesmirror.com/files/spigot/spigot-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar" } } } [1]=> array(1) { ["spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1364.jar"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(46) "spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1364.jar" ["version"]=> array(1) { ["minecraft"]=> string(4) "1.12" } ["size"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(6) "4.10MB" ["bytes"]=> int(4297941) } ["date"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(13) "July 25, 2017" ["epoch"]=> int(1501040531) } ["hashes"]=> array(2) { ["md5"]=> string(32) "c9f7107d886bb349ab5dd6b02c86c97f" ["sha1"]=> string(40) "5f3898abbad835708db330a82864f209bd2bf712" } ["urls"]=> array(2) { ["paid"]=> string(130) "http://sh.st/st/40260a458161ce19c15c6bc46ebe3bd6/http://yivesmirror.com/grab/spigot/spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1364.jar" ["free"]=> string(82) "http://yivesmirror.com/files/spigot/spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1364.jar" } } } [2]=> array(1) { ["spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(39) "spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar" ["version"]=> array(1) { ["minecraft"]=> string(4) "1.12" } ["size"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(8) "857.34kB" ["bytes"]=> int(877913) } ["date"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(13) "July 25, 2017" ["epoch"]=> int(1501040531) } ["hashes"]=> array(2) { ["md5"]=> string(32) "d8f24dbb642125c9f0ce107cd312fc05" ["sha1"]=> string(40) "3048301386c77e1e114c1312493b41ad9a977b52" } ["urls"]=> array(2) { ["paid"]=> string(123) "http://sh.st/st/40260a458161ce19c15c6bc46ebe3bd6/http://yivesmirror.com/grab/spigot/spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar" ["free"]=> string(75) "http://yivesmirror.com/files/spigot/spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1364.jar" } } } [3]=> array(1) { ["spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1363.jar"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(46) "spigot-api-1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded-b1363.jar" ["version"]=> array(1) { ["minecraft"]=> string(4) "1.12" } ["size"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(6) "4.10MB" ["bytes"]=> int(4297941) } ["date"]=> array(2) { ["human"]=> string(13) "July 25, 2017" ["epoch"]=> int(1501040074) } ["hashes"]=> array(2) { ["md5"]=> string(32) "a360db7231f58f61719920b6dd9c7d65" ["sha1"]=> string(40)...
```

---

**UPDATE:**
If you remove `true` parameter from `$json = json_decode($str, true);`


Then your code should work